# How to programmatically set the color or texture of a tab label in JavaFX?

Tags: java, tabs, javafx-2, javafx-8, javafx-css

I have a `TabPane` with several `Tab`s. If the results of an operation in the `Tab` failed, I want to set the `Tab` `Label` to a `Fill` red or perhaps the texture to hashed (for those with color blindness). I want to reset the `Color` back to its default, later.

From reading some of the questions here, one can statically set it using a style sheet.

```
#MyTabPane .tab *.tab-label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

How would one access the `Tab` `label` and set it's color/texture dynamically?

`tab.setStyle("??");`

**ADDITIONS BY ELLTZ**

How can one use inline Styles stated above to change the `Paint` of both the `Label` with style class `tab-label` and the `Button`(`StackPane`) also `tab-close-button`

*code examples needed*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Setting the graphics and styling it did the trick for me:

```
Tab tabB = new Tab();
tabB.setText("");
tabPane.getTabs().add(tabB);
tabB.setStyle("-fx-border-color:red; -fx-background-color: blue;");
tabB.setGraphic(new Label("Tab B"));
tabB.getGraphic().setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #c4d8de;");
```

Comment: Thanks. Surprisingly, if you do tab1.setGraphic(imageView), and then tab2.setGraphic(imageView), the graphic switches from tab1 to tab2. Only one tab has the graphic.

Comment: This is not surprisingly, because a Node can always be only once in the SceneGraph. A "graphic" is a generic Node in the SceneGraph like any Node.

Comment: which makes you wonder why they call it a 'graph' in the first place. But well, yes it is a true, so it is not surprising that the ImageView can only have 1 parent.